# Error en Netbeans/MySQL (Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default-cli))

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, maven

Hace unos días empecé un curso de Java con base de datos MySQL, pero a la hora de correr el programa en Netbeans para que me cree la respectiva tabla en MySQL me salta el error ***Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default-cli) on project jpaPrueba: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]***
Necesito solucionar el problema o no podré avanzar, soy principiante y no entiendo muy bien cómo funciona todo esto
Adjunto evidencia del error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de la clase main la cual ejecuto y me sale el error

---

```
package com.mycompany.jpaprueba;

import com.mycompany.jpaprueba.persistencia.ControladorPersistencia;


public class jpaPrueba {
    public static void main (String[]args)  {
    
        ControladorPersistencia controlPersis = new ControladorPersistencia();
        
        
}  
}
```

---

Y este es mi pom

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpaPrueba</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.aether</groupId>
            <artifactId>aether-spi</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

---

Si necesitan algún código más por favor indicadme.

Comment: Hola Wolfy11, bienvenida, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y añadas tu código (en formato texto) para poder ayudarte, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 1):

Ok después de varios días intentando solucionarlo conseguí lograrlo por mi propia cuenta, incorporé 2 métodos los cuales me sirvieron para que dejara de tirarme error.

1-Especificar dentro del pom cuál era la mainclass.

---

```
<exec.mainClass>com.mycompany.jpaprueba.jpaPrueba</exec.mainClass>
```

---

Es necesario siempre tener en cuenta que la manera correcta de añadir la ejecución de la mainclass es colocando el nombre del paquete que en mi caso fue ***com.mycompany.jpaprueba*** seguido de un punto y luego el nombre de la clase que en mi caso fue ***jpaPrueba***

2-Añadir manualmente la dependencia  mysql también en el pom ya que no me dejaba encontrarla dentro del buscador de dependencias.

---

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

---

Finalmente mi pom terminó de esta manera:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>jpaPrueba</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.aether</groupId>
        <artifactId>aether-spi</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <exec.mainClass>com.mycompany.jpaprueba.jpaPrueba</exec.mainClass>
</properties>
```